# how do I put more than 1 input box and when I click validate it create variable all in once on tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def get_day():

    global day
    day = int(my_box4.get())
    root4.destroy()

root4 = Tk() 
root4.title('ticker')
root4.iconbitmap('E:/projet python/finance.ico')
root4.geometry("400x400")

my_label4 = Label(root4, text = "Enter the begging date")
my_label4.pack(pady = 20)

my_box4 = Entry(root4)
my_box4.pack(pady = 10)

my_button4 = Button(root4, text = "Validate", command = get_day)
my_button4.pack(pady = 20)

answer4 = Label(root4, text='')
answer4.pack(pady = 20)

my_button_quit4 = Button(root4, text = "quit", command = root4.destroy)
my_button_quit4.pack(pady = 30)

root4.mainloop()
```

Dear All,

I am wondering how I can put more than 1 input box on my tkinter box and if I click validate it create variables all at once ?

I do not know if I am very clear

thank you for your help

Sincerely,

Comment: as far as I understand You want to get values from all the Entry widgets with a button press?

Comment: @Matiiss yes it is absolutly that thank you in advance

Comment: first of I am a bit suspicious of why are you naming it `root4`, do You have multiple instances of `Tk()`? also in Your code there is just one Entry widget but basically what You can do is just append them to a list and when pressing button loop over the list and use `.get()` or just manually `.get()` from each Entry instance like: `var1 = instance1.get()`, `var2 = instance2.get()`

Comment: to be honnest I create 4 tkinter box, for the first 3 it is fine to have 1 entry on it but it is not the case for the 4 one witch should have 3 entry, one for the day one for the month and one for the year.

Comment: You shouldn't really use more than one instance of `Tk()`, if You want to have multiple windows You can use `Toplevel`

Comment: I do not know how to create the 3 input box on the same tkinter box

Comment: Add the Tk instance as parent but again You shouldn't use multiple Tk instances instead You can use Toplevel

Comment: do I have to use a class object to do that ?

Comment: You have already created an `Entry` box.  Just create another two `Entry` boxes like the first one.

Comment: Entry already is a class, also as I said for multiple windows use `Toplevel` NOT multiple instances of `Tk`. for more entry boxes: just add them like any other widget, how did You add multiple Labels? the same for Entry